# ImportError: cannot import name py31compat

Tags: macos, python-2.7, jira, py2app

I am attempting to package a python application using py2app. My py2app application successfully builds, but crashes when I run it. The application uses the Jira python module which is where i think the crash is occurring. I am not sure how to proceed. The following is my setup script that i call with `python setup.py py2app`.

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['DataCollector.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    version='0.2beta',
    packages=[

    ],
    license='',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    install_requires=[
          'texttable',
          'python-dateutil',
          'datetime',
          'pytz',
          'pprint',
          'jira',
          'argparse'
    ]
)
```

This is the error when I call it in the console with the command `./DataCollector`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.Trash/AODataCollector/src/dist/DataCollector.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 54, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/price/.Trash/AODataCollector/src/dist/DataCollector.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 49, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/price/.Trash/AODataCollector/src/dist/DataCollector.app/Contents/Resources/DataCollector.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Models.JiraProjectModel import JiraProjectModel
  File "Models/JiraProjectModel.pyc", line 2, in <module>
  File "jira/__init__.pyc", line 6, in <module>
  File "pbr/version.pyc", line 462, in semantic_version
  File "pbr/version.pyc", line 439, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
  File "pkg_resources/__init__.pyc", line 72, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name py31compat
2018-05-18 18:05:11.284 DataCollector[12931:176492] DataCollector Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this solved the problem, but I added a `-A` flag and it works!

`python setup.py py2app -A`